# How to call a function that is coming from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

Here is my robomongo document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("##########"),
"actionname" : "testaction",
"actiontype" : "database.action",
"isshortworkflow" : true,
"processstartedmessage" : "",
"databaseUserName" : "####",
"databasePassword" : "",
"queryTemplate" : "Select * from shop where name=parameters.get("itemName")",
"databaseType" : "MYSQL",
"resultTemplate" : " parameters.get("itemName") + 'has quantity of' + result[0].get('quantity')"
}
```

Here queryTemplate field is having name=parameres.get("itemName").This is a local function in my java code which is going to return as "item1". The problem is that since it is going to come from mongo db it is not going to execute the paramerters.get("itemName") function. Is there a way to execute the function using the string returning from the mongodb.How can I implement inside mongodb?